# How to recognize the folder path and remove it?

Tags: python

I'm doing a log parsing server and receive a list of full path of logs. Now I know the format of folder name must be timestamp like `12-28-2020_11-34-22-026`.
Since I don't know where does user put the log folder. How should I recognize what is the folder path and remove it?

```
INPUT:
    files = [
        '/usr/local/home/username/Downloads/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/log.DEBUG',
        '/usr/local/home/username/Downloads/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/log.INFO',
        '/usr/local/home/username/Downloads/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/summary.txt',
        '/usr/local/home/username/Downloads/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/UnitTest/ResultSheet_2020-12-28_11-34-37.txt',
        '/usr/local/home/username/Downloads/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/UnitTest/Emulator8080/logcat_emulator_8080_12-28-2020_11-34-24-826.txt',
    ]

OUTPUT:
    files = [
        '/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/log.DEBUG',
        '/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/log.INFO',
        '/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/summary.txt',
        '/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/UnitTest/ResultSheet_2020-12-28_11-34-37.txt',
        '/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/UnitTest/Emulator8080/logcat_emulator_8080_12-28-2020_11-34-24-826.txt',
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check what (first) part of a path matches some pattern.

The pattern you're matching as a regex:

```
re.compile(r'^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}$')
```

Python's standard library `pathlib` has a very robust way of splitting the path using the `Path` class' `.parts` property, so you can find the match:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path


files = [
    '/usr/local/home/username/Downloads/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/log.DEBUG',
    '/usr/local/home/username/Downloads/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/log.INFO',
    '/usr/local/home/username/Downloads/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/summary.txt',
    '/usr/local/home/username/Downloads/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/UnitTest/ResultSheet_2020-12-28_11-34-37.txt',
    '/usr/local/home/username/Downloads/12-28-2020_11-34-22-026/UnitTest/Emulator8080/logcat_emulator_8080_12-28-2020_11-34-24-826.txt',
]


rgx = re.compile(r'^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}$')

log_files = []
for fn in files:
    for i, part in enumerate(Path(fn).parts):
        if rgx.match(part):
            # str() because you're asking for strings, but could just leave them as paths
            log_files.append(str(Path(*Path(fn).parts[i:])))
            break

print(log_files)
```

Output:

```
['12-28-2020_11-34-22-026\\log.DEBUG', '12-28-2020_11-34-22-026\\log.INFO', '12-28-2020_11-34-22-026\\summary.txt', '12-28-2020_11-34-22-026\\UnitTest\\ResultSheet_2020-12-28_11-34-37.txt', '12-28-2020_11-34-22-026\\UnitTest\\Emulator8080\\logcat_emulator_8080_12-28-2020_11-34-24-826.txt']
```

What this part `log_files.append(str(Path(*Path(fn).parts[i:])))` does:

- appends a new result to `log_files`
- the result is the string representation `str()` of the `Path()` created from the parts of `Path(fn)` from index `i` and onwards.
  `Path()` expects the parts as separate arguments, so the list is spread with the spreading operator `*`.
- after the match is found and the remaining parts combined and appended, the loop can stop (`break`), since even if the pattern occurs again, you don't want it to match again for that path.

Mind you, in your desired outcome, you have all the paths start with a `/` - I think that's a mistake, as that would suggest the paths start in the root, while they are paths relative to some other folders. But of course you can add the `/` if you need it somehow.